# Using custom video Effects with MediaElement

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, mediaelement

I have an application that uses MediElement to play videos and provides it with a custom video effects implemented in C++\CX via MediaElement.AddVideoEffect method.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.addvideoeffect

And it works just fine. But there is a bit of a problem, - When user hits the "Pause" button, MediaElement stops calling ProccessFrame method of the video effects I attach. Which leads to the situation, when user can tweak his effect whilst video is playing, but cannot do it on Pause.

So basically, I'm wondering if there is a workaround.

Thank you for the time and effort.

Kind regards.

Comment: I have replied a similar question in [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/579db1b1-beae-40f5-8b82-9e346ec5f1b9/uwpupdate-same-frame-for-videoeffect-during-pausemode-mediaelement-addvideoeffect-xaml-uwp-?forum=wpdevelop). It’s my thinking. You could try it to see if it will work.